# Copy file with relative path

Tags: powershell

I would like to copy all files of a certain type from a certain sub-directory with their relative path from that sub-directory to another directory with the relative path intact. e.g.:

Source sub-dir:

```
c:\temp\sourcedirectory
```

Source files:

```
c:\temp\sourcedirectory\tonymontana\fileOne.txt
c:\temp\sourcedirectory\poker\fileTwo.txt
```

Target dir:

```
c:\temp\targetdirectory
```

Desired result:

```
c:\temp\targetdirectory\tonymontana\fileOne.txt
c:\temp\targetdirectory\poker\fileTwo.txt
```

So far I've come up with:

```
Set-Location $srcRoot
Get-ChildItem -Path $srcRoot -Filter $filePattern -Recurse |
    Resolve-Path -Relative |
    Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $buildroot $_.FullName}
```

However, this "everything is an object" à la PowerShell is beating me down (at least that's what I suspect). I.e. the files gets copied, but without their relative path.

Anyone who could enlighten me a bit?

Comment: *"Anyone who could enlighten me a bit?"* - It looks like Microsoft took something simple that worked, and complicated it to the point it no longer works. Its sad when developers have to go online and lookup how to use a copy command. What an epic engineering failure on Microsoft's part.

Comment: @jww Dude, what are you talking about? Regular copy commands do not copy files with their relative path, and never have. That always required either scripting or the use of specialized tools like `xcopy`, `robocopy`, `rsync`, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't bother with PowerShell cmdlets for this, simply use `robocopy`:

```
robocopy C:\temp\sourcedirectory C:\temp\targetdirectory *.txt /s
```

Comment: How can you not use PowerShell when that's the only shell you have?

Comment: @jww Please read carefully. `robocopy` works in PowerShell as it does in CMD. You don't need PowerShell **cmdlets** for this kind of task.

Comment: The subject "Copy with relative path" is not addressed by an answer using absolute paths.  This Q&A is about how to copy a folder structure with files from one absolute path to another.

Comment: @user1748217 The OP gives the source and target directories as absolute paths in the question; this answer just uses those so that it matches the question. The part about relative paths is because the OP requires preserving the paths *relative to* the source directory. But I presume this answer works equally well when the source and target directories are given as relative paths.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
$srcroot = "c:\temp\sourcedirectory"
$builroot= "c:\temp\targetdirectory"
gci -path $srcroot -filter $filepattern -recurse | 
  % { Copy-Item $_.FullName -destination ($_.FullName -replace [regex]::escape($srcroot),$builroot) }
```

Comment: Got some sort of issue here with the replace action, the build dir didn't get prepended, the source was removed however. Probably a "DOOH! mistake at my end. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Copy-item $srcRoot -destination $destination -recurse
```

Comment: This will include the actual srcRoot in the relative path, of course I could just iterate over sub-dirs from srcRoot and pipe those according to your suggestion together with the filter parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent copying the folder itself i.e. creating

```
c:\temp\targetdirectory\sourcedirectory
```

Change into the source folder, then use a wildcard instead of the folder as the source:

```
cd C:\temp\sourcedirectory\
Copy-item * -destination c:\temp\targetdirectory -recurse`
```